# Visual Basic add event in .NET 1.1

Tags: vb.net, events

I don't have a lighting bolt at the top like I normally do to add events.  How do I add events in .NET 1.1 for Visual basic 2002?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if Visual Studio 2002 had this or not, but look in the properties window for the object (if this is a form or something like that) and there will be a lightning bolt there you can click on to see events, otherwise just create your event handler method and add "Handles Me.SomeEvent" on the end of the method definition.